# Given only uniform distribution, using mathematical transformation to derive number draw from various distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

If I only have a random number generator `rand` which generates a random number from a uniform distribution in `[0,1]`, would it be possible to use some smart mathematical transformation to:

1. generate a value from a normal distribution with mean = 0 and variance = 1
2. generate a value from a poisson distribution with mean = 60

Thanks!

Comment: You can always use the inverse function to the CDF.  But there are better answers.  Look up Box-Muller transformation for generating standard normal random variables.  Also, there are fast approximate methods for approximating the Poisson CDF.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
F(x) = P(X \leq x)
$$
for the cumulative distribution function of the random variable you are trying to simulate. This is increasing so invertible. Take $Y = F^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is your uniform random variable. Then
$$
P(Y \leq y)= P(F_X^{-1}(U) \leq y) = P(U \leq F_X(y)) = F_X(y) = P(X \leq y)
$$
So the distribution of $Y$ is the same as that of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

If $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ and if random variable $X$ has inverse CDF (quantile function) $F^{-1}_X(t),$ then a realization $u$ of $U$ produces a realization
$F^{-1}_X(u)$ of $X.$

For example, if $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1),$ then we have PDF $f_X(x) = e^{-x},$
CDF $F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-x},$ and quantile function $F_X^{-1}(t) = -\log(1-t),$
for $x > 0, 0 < t < 1).$ Thus if you generate a sample of size 10,000 from
$U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0, 1),$ then $X = -\log(1 - U) \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1).$

This can be demonstrated in R statistical software as shown below. [In R,
`runif` generates a sample from a uniform distribution and `dexp` is an
exponential PDF.]

```
set.seed(917);  u = runif(10^4);  x = -log(1-u)
summary(u)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.000243 0.280017 0.677848 0.981355 1.363933 7.717536 

hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dexp(x), 0, 8, add=T, col="red", lwd=2, n = 10001)
```

In the figure below, the histogram shows the 10,000 simulated values $X$
and the curve is the density of $\mathsf{Exp}(1).$

[image]

This 'quantile method' works easily if the CDF of $X$ can be written in
closed form and then inverted to find the quantile function of $X.$ 
The idea can often be extended more widely by finding a rational approximation
of the CDF and inverting it.

In R, a random sample of size `n` from a standard unform
distribution can be generated with `rnorm(n)` which is (a few technical
details for optimization notwithstanding) essentially `qnorm(runif(n))`, where
`qnorm` uses Michael Wichura's rational approximation to the normal quantile
function. (The approximation is accurate to the degree that can be represented
by double precision arithmetic.)

```
set.seed(918);  z = qnorm(runif(10^5))
summary(z)
       Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 -4.283920 -0.673689  0.004902  0.005624  0.683117  4.532156
```

[image]

An entirely different method, specific to normal distributions, is used by the
'Box-Muller transformation' which generates two standard normal variates from
two standard uniform ones. [One nice explanation is given in Wikipedia.]